# nodejs - express sending pdf as downlaod in response

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

Hi I'm trying to setup a node server to send a pdf file to the user when the user does a post request to it.

the problem is that it doesn't start the download, but I see this in the console. [image]

here is my code

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

mypdf.toPdf(__dirname + "/my-invoice.pdf", function (err, data) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(data.stream.path);
  stream.pipe(res);

 stream.on('data', function(data) {
    res.write(data);
  });

  stream.on('end', function() {
    res.end();
  });
});
```

});

I also tried using some different settings for the headers

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
    res.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;      filename=\"test.pdf\"");
    next();
});
```

Comment: if you already have `.pipe(res)` you don't need `res.write`, they're both doing same thing twice

Comment: Okay, thanks! 
Could that be causing the file not to download?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer in the wrong place I just needed to handle the file coming from the server in the client code the right way.

```
    $http.get('https://dam-pdf.herokuapp.com/15-0123', {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).success(function(response){
        var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        window.open($scope.content)
    })
```